# More information on jQuery snippet

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

```
var VarHere;

(function (VarHere) {
    // Code here    
    var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({});

    $(function () {
        VarHere.SomeController = new SomeView({
            el: $someContainer
        });
    });
})(VarHere || (VarHere = {}));
```

What is going on in this snippet? I've seen it used in some BackBone js implementations.

I know what the stuff inside the jQuery ready block does, and basically sets up VarHere, but what is the (function(VarHere) { and closing part all about? What is the significance of it?

Answer (score 2):

Its an anonymous function wich is auto called passing `VarHere`  as param if defined or empty object

```
function(param){...} //this is anonymous function
```

using:

```
(function(param){...})(param) //make this function called  passing param as parameter of this anonymous function
```

Why using `(VarHere || (VarHere = {}))` ?

This way, you are sure your parameter `VarHere` is defined inside the called function.

Usually for jquery plugin, you see too:

```
(function(param, undefined){...})(param)
```

Here you want to be sure undefined inside function is what you expect it to be. You are passing only one parameter to a function which expect two parameters, second parameter is 'undefined'.

This is because in javascript, `undefined` is not a protected keyword: `var undefined = "something i don't expect";` is still possible.

Of course, this function create a closure, all variables declared inside are not visible from the global scope.